# Kubernetes - Ingress ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE everytime

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

im trying to make my first kubernetes project, but the problem is that i may have some configuration issues.
For example i wanted to run this project:

```
https://gitlab.com/codeching/kubernetes-multicontainer-application-react-nodejs-postgres-nginx
```

I did:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.46.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

Then

```
kubectl apply -f k8s
```

But when i enter the `http://localhost` i just get `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`
Anyone knows why? I have newly installed docker desktop & kubernetes, everything is green & working, but somehow i can't run even this simple project.

Answer (score 0):

The ingress-nginx ingress service is getting deployed as LoadBalancer Service type.  if LoadBalancer is not attached, you can use [port forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) of the service to access applications in the cluster.